# Ember, relations, and multiple calls

Tags: ember.js, foreign-keys

EDIT

Sorry, my endpoint does not communicate data correctly, it is not an EMBER problem.

I have a route with the following model :

```
model() {
const produit= this.modelFor('produits.edit');
return Ember.RSVP.hash({
  produit: produit
});
},
```

When I disclay produit.licences it shows all the licence from the produit.

If I modify the model to get a list of all existing licences:

```
model() {
    const produit = this.modelFor('produits.edit');
    const allLicences = this.get('store').findAll('licence');
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      produit: produit ,
      allLicences
    });
  }
```

To get a list of licences that can be added to the product, I end up with all the licence in produit.licences.

Why does ember act like that? Des he assume every licence in memory is linked to the produit?

EDIT

the relation in licence.js : `produits: DS.hasMany('produit'),`

The relation in produit.js : `licences: DS.hasMany('licence')`

Comment: Where are you declaring the constant allLicenses?  and am I right that your Ember models show product.licenses as a hasMany?  and license.products as a hasMany?

Comment: Yes it is a many to many relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.At first glance it looks like `produit` like typo but then you are using it like that, any how you can verify that also.

in one place you are getting it like `this.modelFor('produits.edit')` and in other place you are getting like this `this.modelFor('products.edit')`.

2. `this.modelFor('produits.edit').licences` instead of you can always use `get` method to properties available.

```
    model() {
        const produitLicences = this.modelFor('produits.edit').get('licences');
        const allLicences = this.get('store').findAll('licence');
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
          produitLicences: produitLicences,
          allLicences
        });
      }
```

Comment: For the 1 I translated to produit to product to ask the question and forgot about it.

Comment: It's another problem, but if I return the licences of the produit instead of the produit, I cannot iterate over it in the view with #each.